# Why alert() dialog shows first regardless of order in the code?

Tags: javascript

In the code sample below, I expect the text in div to change first.

But the text changes only after I click ok in the alert dialog.

```js
var x = 0;

function counter() {
  x++;

  document.getElementById('aDiv').innerHTML = x;
  alert(x);
}
```

```html
<div id="aDiv">
0
</div>
<input type="button" value="+1" onclick="counter()">
```

Comment: where do you get this behaviour?

Comment: The page doesn't get chance to refresh before the alert is shown.  If you delay the alert even by a millisecond then you'll see the page update first.

Comment: It depends on the browser you're using. Try this in chrome and firefox, you'll get different behaviours. In Firefox, the content will be updated before the alert is shown. In Chrome, it will be updated after the alert is closed.

Comment: @RogerC - That's very interesting (and I've just verified it). Firefox used to be *less* proactive with rendering DOM updates than Chrome, but now appears to be *more* proactive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most browsers render changes to the DOM only *between* JavaScript tasks. (JavaScript code is run as discrete tasks in an event loop, aka jobs in a job queue.) `alert` and its cousins `confirm` and `prompt` are archaic stop-the-world functions that completely block the event loop and UI. So although your change to the DOM has been made, the browser hasn't had a chance to render that change visually before the `alert` stops the world.

If you really, really need to use `alert`, do so after a timeout:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    alert(/*...*/);
}, 100);
```

```js
var x = 0;

function counter() {
  x++;

  document.getElementById('aDiv').innerHTML = x;
  setTimeout(function() {
    alert(x);
  }, 100);
}
```

```html
<div id="aDiv">
0
</div>
<input type="button" value="+1" onclick="counter()">
```

A delay of `0` is sufficient to give most browsers a chance to do the rendering, but I've generally had to use 100 with Firefox when I've needed to do this. (That may relate only to slightly-older versions of Firefox, though; with the current Firefox I see the DOM change in your snippet even without `setTimeout`. That's at least newish behavior as I write this in May 2018.)

Answer (score 1):

The browser do not update the DOM immediately. You can add a delay before calling the alert() function:

```
setTimeout(function(){ alert(x) }, 10);
```

Comment: @Archer I know and it will let the DOM time to update before alert function block everything... Why downvote?

Comment: @Archer I know what you mean now but your comment say the opposite :) i update my answer

Answer (score 1):

Modern browsers are set up such that once they encounter `alert()` browser will essentially pause the rendering of HTML until the `alert()` is done.